# Error Using the docx library

Tags: c++, visual-c++, docx

I am attempting to familiarize myself with the DocxFactory Library (library for c++ that helps with docx)

[DocxLibrary Tutorial](http://docxfactory.com/tutorial/)

Currently attempting to do exercise one which involves  running the following to generate a docx template.

```
#include "WordProcessingMerger.h"
#include "WordProcessingCompiler.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <exception> 
#include <ctime> 
#include <tchar.h>



using namespace DocxFactory;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    try
    {
        WordProcessingCompiler& l_compiler =
            WordProcessingCompiler::getInstance();
        time_t l_start = clock();
        l_compiler.compile(
            "/opt/DocxFactory/exercises/templates/top_level_items.docx",
            "/opt/DocxFactory/exercises/templates/top_level_items.dfw");
        cout << "Completed (in "
            << (double)(clock() - l_start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC
            << " seconds)."
            << endl;
    }
    catch (const exception& p_exception)
    {
        cout << p_exception.what() << endl;
    }
} // main
```

I run into around 50 errors many of which i assume are linking errors (i suspect it's due to improper library configuration).
Such as 
LINK 2019
LINK 1120

I've looked at multiple results for those errors but no luck.

I have done the following steps in visual studio 2013

1. Add the DocxFactory\bin\ directory to the Windows PATH
2. Add the DocxFactory/include/ directory to the list of include directories
3. Link to the DocxFactory.lib library under the linker section
4. Include the corresponding DocxFactory.lib under the Linker input
5. Included the .cpp files and .h files in the code

I'm unsure of which step i missed, or if its due to my unfamiliarity of using external libraries.

EDIT
I've reinstalled it and have gotten it down to three errors (fixed a tiny PATH error)

Error   3   error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals   c:\users\100489004\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\docxfinal\Debug\docxfinal.exe  1   1   docxfinal
Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static class DocxFactory::WordProcessingCompiler & __cdecl DocxFactory::WordProcessingCompiler::getInstance(void)" (?getInstance@WordProcessingCompiler@DocxFactory@@SAAAV12@XZ) referenced in function _main    c:\Users\100489004\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\docxfinal\docxfinal\Source.obj docxfinal
Error   2   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall DocxFactory::WordProcessingCompiler::compile(class std::basic_string,class std::allocator > const &,class std::basic_string,class std::allocator > const &)" (?compile@WordProcessingCompiler@DocxFactory@@QAEXABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@0@Z) referenced in function _main   c:\Users\100489004\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\docxfinal\docxfinal\Source.obj docxfinal

Something interesting to note when i add the .cpp two corresponding cpp files as per instructions it appears to break the linker so the amount of errors jump to 50 again. So for now  i simply have chosen not to included the .cpp files in the project. Unsure if this is correct or not

Comment: Did you miss one of the steps in the [Windows Installation Chapter](http://docxfactory.com/tutorial/) eventually?

Comment: no i'm pretty sure i followed the instructions to the letter in regards to that tutorial